# How to acess a variable from a structure located in a header file?

Tags: c, struct

I am trying to gain access to the variable `New_Id` located in a structure within the header file 'Header.h'. This is being done from a c file called Main.c

```
 Header.h
 #ifndef HEADER.H
 #define HEADER.H

 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdint.h>

 typedef struct {
    uint32 New_Id;
  } IdType;
```

I am trying to acess this variable and assign it a value from my C file 'Main.c' in the following way

```
 #include <Header.h>
 #include <stdint.h>
 #include <stdio.h>

 void Main (void) {

     //code independent of the structure.-----

     -----------------------------------//

     //Now accessing the structure variable//

     IdType.New_id =2;

  }
```

However for some reason that I don't understand it keeps saying 'Field New_Id could not be resolved'. It does not say thisd for the structure itself. Could somebody please tell me what am I doing wrong here.

Comment: structures don't have variables, but fields (or members).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`IdType` is a data type.For accessing the variable you need to create object of type `IdType` as follows :

```
IdType id;
id.New_id=2;
```

Answer (score 3):

In your code, `IdType` itself is not a variable, it is a data type. You need to have a variable of that type to access a member of that structure variable.

Comment: That was a stupid mistake. Thank you for that help :)